# I want to display Tabbar in one of my fragment in layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 3 fragments (two in verticle and one in horizontal with one of the vertical fragment) in the main layout in one of that fragment I want to Display Tabbars.
and in each tab click event it has their own layout again

Comment: I tried with tabhost but it gives me runtime exeception  -- Manu

Comment: You need to post some details, at least the full Stacktrace of the exception and the relevant pieces of code